# Tensorflow serving on docker is slower than running inference directly on flask server

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, tensorflow-serving

I have tried setting up Tensorflow Serving on docker and when I compare its inference speed against running the model on my flask server and doing inferences, the flask server one is a lot faster by almost 1-2 seconds. Are there options I need to tweak for TF serving such as disabling batching or should I just stick with running it locally in my flask server. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.